# how can i dynamycially add a page link on another page in angular

Tags: angular

> I am using angular9,I create a login page in login page  below login
>   from i provide my registration page li but when i click on my
>   :register now" button it cannot open my registration page it . below i
>   add my codes ,i dont know where i make a mistake.
>
> A cookie associated with a cross-site resource at http://google.com/
>   was set without the `SameSite` attribute. A future release of Chrome
>   will only deliver cookies with cross-site requests if they are set
>   with `SameSite=None` and `Secure`. You can review cookies in developer
>   tools under Application>Storage>Cookies and see more details at
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5088147346030592 and
>   https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5633521622188032.
>
> login.component.html

```
<div class="app-body">
      <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-8 mx-auto">
              <div class="card-group">
                <div class="card p-4">
                  <div class="card-body">
                    <form>
                      <h1>Login</h1>
                      <p class="text-muted">Sign In to your account</p>
                      <small *ngIf='invalidLogin'>{{errorMessage}}</small>
                      <div class="input-group mb-3">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username"  [(ngModel)]="username" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
                          true}" autocomplete="username" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="input-group mb-4">
                        <div class="input-group-prepend">
                          <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                        </div>
                        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" [(ngModel)]="password" [ngModelOptions]="{standalone:
                          true}"  autocomplete="current-password" required>
                      </div>
                      <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-6">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary px-4" (click)=handleLogin()>Login</button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-6 text-right">
                          <button type="button" class="btn btn-link px-0">Forgot password?</button>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </form>
                  </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card text-white bg-primary py-5 d-md-down-none" style="width:44%">
                  <div class="card-body text-center">
                    <div>
                      <h2>Sign up</h2>
                      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua.</p>
                      <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary active mt-3">Register Now!</button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

> registration.component.html

```
 <div class="app-body">
      <main class="main d-flex align-items-center">
        <div class="container">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 mx-auto">
              <div class="card mx-4">
                <div class="card-body p-4">
                  <form>
                    <h1>Register</h1>
                    <p class="text-muted">Create your account</p>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Username" autocomplete="username" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text">@</span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Email" autocomplete="email" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-3">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
                    </div>
                    <div class="input-group mb-4">
                      <div class="input-group-prepend">
                        <span class="input-group-text"><i class="icon-lock"></i></span>
                      </div>
                      <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Repeat password" autocomplete="new-password" required>
                    </div>
                    <button type="button" class="btn  btn-success">Create Account</button>
                  </form>
                </div>
                <div class="card-footer p-4">
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <button class="btn btn-block btn-facebook" type="button"><span>facebook</span></button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-6">
                      <button class="btn btn-block btn-twitter" type="button"><span>twitter</span></button>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </main>
    </div>
```

> Login.component.ts

```
  import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { Router } from "@angular/router";
    import { HardcodeauthService } from '../../service/hardcodeauth.service';


    @Component({
      selector: 'app-dashboard',
      templateUrl: 'login.component.html'
    })
    export class LoginComponent implements  OnInit{

      username ='nilmani'
      password = 'rock'
      errorMessage='Invalid Credential'
      invalidLogin = false

      constructor( private router : Router,
        private hardcodeauthservice :HardcodeauthService){}

      ngOnInit(){

      }
      handleLogin(){
        // if (this.username==='nilmani' && this.password==='dumy') {
        if (this.hardcodeauthservice.authenticate(this.username,this.password)) {
          this.router.navigate(['dashboard'])
          this.invalidLogin=false
        }else{
          this.invalidLogin=true
        }
        // console.log(this.username)
        // console.log(this.password)
      }

     }
```

> registration.component.ts

```
import { Component,OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from "@angular/router";

@Component({
  selector: 'app-dashboard',
  templateUrl: 'register.component.html'
})
export class RegisterComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private router : Router) { }

  ngOnInit(){

  }
  registerNow(){
      this.router.navigate(['registration'])
  }

}
```

Comment: am I missing something or did you only provide the html and ask us what is wrong with the javascript code? where is the code for handleLogin()?

Comment: here is my   login.component.ts  where  I define my handleLogin() method

Comment: const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'first-component', component: Register }

]; add routing module like this and in this.route.navigate('Firstcomponent')

Answer (score 0):

you don't have any (click) event on your Register Now! button. you need a registerNow() function that routes to your registration page. and a click event that routes it there.

```
<button type="button" class="btn  btn-success">Register Now!</button>
```

should be:

```
<button type="button" (click)="registerNow()" class="btn  btn-success">Register Now!</button>
```

or:

```
<button type="button" [routerLink]="['/register-now']" class="btn  btn-success">Register Now!</button>
```

have you created a registration page and added it to your router?